# Creando atajos de teclado con pynput listener

Tags: python, hilos, keyboard

Estoy tratando de crear un script que al activar la tecla de acceso rápido escucha la siguiente tecla presionada y la busca en un diccionario para devolver un valor. Cuando depuro funciona correctamente, pero cuando hago la ejecución normal no responde correctamente, creo que se debe al manejo de subprocesos, pero no sé cómo solucionarlo.

```
import keyboard
import ast
from pynput import keyboard as kb

keyboard_events={}
path = 'D:\\shortcuts.ini'
file = open(path, 'r')
content = file.read()
keyboard_events = ast.literal_eval(content)
current = set()

def on_activate():
    print('Global hotkey activated!')
    try:
        c = keyboard.read_key()
    except:
        print()
    if c in keyboard_events:
        print(keyboard_events[c])
        keyboard.write(keyboard_events[c])


def for_canonical(f):
    return lambda k: f(l.canonical(k))

hotkey = kb.HotKey(
    kb.HotKey.parse('<ctrl>+<shift>'),
    on_activate)
with kb.Listener(
        on_press=for_canonical(hotkey.press),
        on_release=for_canonical(hotkey.release)) as l:
    l.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

SOLUCIONADO, el problema no eran los hilos, sino que usando las *hotkeys*, las teclas se quedaban "pulsadas". Comparto la solución

```
import keyboard
import ast
from pynput import keyboard as kb
import time

keyboard_events={}
path = 'shortcuts.ini'
file = open(path, 'r')
content = file.read()
keyboard_events = ast.literal_eval(content)
current = set()

def on_activate():
    time.sleep(0.1)
    keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl')
    keyboard.press_and_release('shift')
    time.sleep(0.1)
    c = keyboard.read_key()

    if c == 'ctrl' or 'mayusculas':
        c = keyboard.read_key()

    if c in keyboard_events:
        keyboard.press('backspace')
        keyboard.write(keyboard_events[c])


def for_canonical(f):
    return lambda k: f(l.canonical(k))

hotkey = kb.HotKey(
    kb.HotKey.parse('<ctrl>+<shift>'),
    on_activate)
with kb.Listener(
        on_press=for_canonical(hotkey.press),
        on_release=for_canonical(hotkey.release)) as l:
    l.join()
```

Comment: esta condición `if c == 'ctrl' or 'mayusculas'` esta mal. Ahí hay 2 condiciones, la primera es `c=='ctrl'` lo cual dependiendo del valor de `c` será `True` o `False` y la segunda condición es `'mayusculas'` que **siempre** será `True` por ser una cadena no vacía. Creo que tal vez quisiste hacer `if c == 'ctrl' or c=='mayusculas'` que se puede resumir a `if c in  ['ctrl' ,'mayusculas']`

Comment: Cierto! Aun me pierdo un poco en la sintaxis de Python, gracias!